# Orientability of simplicial complex

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, simplicial-complex

Suppose $K$ is an abstract simplicial complex. We know $K$ has a geometric realization |K|, Suppose $|K|$ is a manifold, Is there any necessary and sufficient condition on $K$ for orientability of |K|?

Comment: I know what orientability means for a manifold, but not for an arbitrary simplicial complex.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Apologize, I forgot it, I mean $|K|$ is a manifold.

Comment: Don't you just need an orientation on each maximal simplex, which is compatible with intersections along facets?

Comment: Yes, I need this, But my question is "Always, Is there a compatible orientation?"

Comment: No, since there are nonorientable surfaces (like projective space) that admit triangulations.

Comment: One example of a necessary and sufficient condition is that the sum of all the n-simplices is a cycle in integral homology. An example of a sufficient condition is having odd order fundamental group.